# PostgreSQL 9.0 replace function not working for one character

Tags: postgresql

im working with PostgreSQl 9.0
and i have a table from which i need to replace a character with ''(blank space)
for that im using

> update species set engname = replace(engname, '', '');

(this is the query image)
[image]

(image is posted)
[image: this is the character]

in the case **species** is the table and **engname** is the field(character varying)..

the contens of one of the row is

> " -tellifer fÃ‚Ârthii"
>   [image]

even after firing the query the character is not replaced.
i have tried with

> update species set sciname = regexp_replace(sciname, '', '') 
>   but the character doesnot get replace

my **database** is

```
   CREATE DATABASE myDB
   WITH OWNER = Myadmin
   ENCODING   = 'SQL_ASCII'
   TABLESPACE = pg_default
   LC_COLLATE = 'C'
   LC_CTYPE = 'C'
   CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

We are planning to move to UTF-8 encoding but during conversion with **iconv** the conversion fails because of this [image]
so i wanted to **replace** the character with..
can anyone tell me how to remove that character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this symbol can be used for more characters - so you cannot to use replace. Probably your client application uses a different encoding than database. Symbol is used to signalisation broken encoding.

Solution is using correct encoding

```
postgres=# select * from ff;
       a       
───────────────
 žluťoučký kůň
(1 row)

postgres=# set client_encoding to 'latin2'; --setting wrong encoding
SET
postgres=# select * from ff; -- and you can see strange symbols
       a       
───────────────
 �lu�ou�k� k�
(1 row)

postgres=# set client_encoding to 'utf8'; -- setting good encoding
SET
postgres=# select * from ff;
       a       
───────────────
 žluťoučký kůň
(1 row)
```

Other solution is replacing national or special chars by related ascii characters

9.x has unaccent contrib module for utf or for some 8bites encoding there is function to_ascii()

Comment: hey thank you nice explanation,...but how can replace/remove that character?..i need to replace/remove it so that the **iconv** can encode the dump file to UTF-8..because with the character the **iconv** is failing when it encounter that character.

Comment: you have to find correct encoding, or use -c parameter for iconv